# How to debug "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of xxx bytes exhausted" in PHP

Tags: php

What is the best strategy to debug a "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted " error? This error i'm getting is strange and something is obviously wrong. The function which is causing it is

```
/**
 * Flush all output buffers for PHP 5.2.
 *
 * Make sure all output buffers are flushed before our singletons our destroyed.
 *
 * @since 2.2.0
 */
function wp_ob_end_flush_all() {
    $levels = ob_get_level();
    for ($i=0; $i<$levels; $i++)
        ob_end_flush();
}
```

i simply rebased some code i was working on and started getting this. 
what's your strategy to debug this?

Comment: Why are you looping through `$levels` like that? When you call `ob_end_flush()`, you're wiping out the OB anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below code, if your code reaches the specified number of bytes it just echo it and exit. instead of crashing :

```
function wp_ob_end_flush_all() {
    $levels = ob_get_level();
    for ($i=0; $i<$levels; $i++){
        ob_end_flush();
        if(memory_get_peak_usage() > 268435400) { // 268435456 
            echo memory_get_peak_usage(). ' reached! now we should stop the script.' ;
            break; // or die();
        } 
    }
}
```

**Update**
To answer your question, one way to debug leaking is to use [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) another way it to use the function I gave in the example or wrap your suspicious functions by `memory_get_usage` and compare the difference.

Comment: i'm using 256MB and something is leaking. i can't change that function, it's wordpress, i just wanted to know if there was an easy way to detetct what function was causing the leakage. It's a twig render call actually.

Comment: Thank you very much. My case was caused by "oversize" text column data. It was a problem caused by my auto-post software. I wonder if user can abuse web interface to insert huge text data to crash my site

Comment: @PhamHuyAnh you need to always expect worst case scenarios and make your code robust by adding all kind of checks to avoid attacks, you can even change the server configuration in some scenario, but to answer your question, yes user can always crash your system either with good or bad intention, it is your responsibility to avoid that to happen, also think about adding logging to your application to keep track of what is going on.

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting this error upon starting the Apache server with EasyPhp-Devserver-16.1.

In my case, it was because Easy php was trying to load a too large error.log file.

Deleting the old server log in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\httpserver\apache2418x160331124251\logs
```

and creating an empty one solved my problem.

Hope this can help others.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you reach memory limit, the solution is not bypassing it, enlarging the allowed size, or give a controlled error. what you have to do is to find what is causing that overflow.

You are using 256Mb, and consuming all them in a loop concerning just output buffers, so something is wrong.

first to do, check how many iterations you are trying to do

```
function wp_ob_end_flush_all() {
    $levels = ob_get_level();
     die ($levels); 
}
```

Comment: i'm using 256MB and something is leaking. i can't change that function, it's wordpress, i just wanted to know if there was an easy way to detetct what function was causing the leakage

Comment: if you get the error in that very function, the error will be in some function starting with ob_ (output buffer) or in some function writing to the buffer, this is, potentially any one. so it will be hard. you can try with xdebug. Any ways, did you try what i say of die ($levels)? it will print the number of nested buffers, and if there are few, would be complicated, but if this number is very big, you have a clue of what is happening, and probably you can solve it faster. if you do it, please come back and tell what number did you get

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because Easyphp was trying to load a too large error.log file.
Deleting the server log file in `eds-binaries\httpserver\apache2418x160331124251\logs` helped me solve the problem.